PointCloud2 Data Not Being Used as Obstacles in Obstacle Layer
I am having issues adding PointCloud data to the costmap as obstacles. The data is coming from a /marker_to_pointcloud topic that takes visualization_msgs/MarkerArray and publishes into PointCloud2.
I then add that topic in my list of observation sources for the costmap as such:

global_costmap:
  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,    type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: virtual_layer,   type: "virtual_costmap_layer::VirtualLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
...
  obstacle_layer:
    enabled: true
    observation_sources:  laser_scan_sensor camera_sensor
    laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: lidar_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
    camera_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_link, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /realsense_pointcloud2, marking: true, clearing: true}
    obstacle_range: 10.0
    raytrace_range: 10.0
    min_obstacle_height: -0.5
    max_obstacle_height: 1.5
    combination_method: 1
    debug: true


local_costmap:
  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,    type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

  # 各TFフレームの設定
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint

  # #inflation_layerの設定
  inflation_layer:
    enabled: true
    inflation_radius: 0.2
    cost_scaling_factor: 15.8


  # 更新頻度の設定
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 3.0

  # ローカルコストマップの計算範囲
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0

  # ローカルコストマップの解像度
  resolution: 0.05

  # タイムスタンプのずれの許容量
  transform_tolerance: 0.5

  static_layer:
    enabled: true
    map_topic: "/map"
    track_unknown_space: false
    subscribe_to_updates: true
  
  obstacle_layer:
    observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor camera_sensor
    laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: lidar_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
    camera_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_link, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /realsense_pointcloud2, marking: true, clearing: true}
    obstacle_range: 10.0
    raytrace_range: 10.0
    min_obstacle_height: -0.5
    max_obstacle_height: 1.5
    debug: true

I made sure I am calling those yaml files in my move_base launch file.
Additionally, I checked the ranges for the PointCloud to make sure the min_obstacle_height , max_obstacle_height  are within range by listening to /realsense_pointcloud2  in the following way:
def callback(data):
    points = list(pc2.read_points(data, field_names=("x", "y", "z"), skip_nans=True))
    for point in points:
        x, y, z = point
        print(f"x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}")

a snippet of the results:
x: 0.6240000128746033, y: -0.1398918330669403, z: 0.0
x: 0.6506802439689636, y: -0.16479024291038513, z: 0.0
I`ve added screenshots of Rviz with and without the laserscan topic, since this does get taken as an obstacle, for clarity


and also I have added the visualization of just the costmap, you can see some overlapping with the pointcloud but that is coming from the laserscan that detects the obstacle as well.
Additional info:
The Marker comes from a YOLO bounding box for humans using a RealSense D435 camera, which gets projected into the map.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04,ROS1 Noetic. Any help is appreciated and I`m glad to give more info :))
** edit: the way I solved this was to add the points I was interested in as a virtual costmap layer , so they are reflected in the costmap.

The issue got solved by taking a different approach. I used a virtual costmap layer and extracted the points I was interested in and added them to said layer that modifies the costmap and is also used by the path planner. (I now have different issued with frame transforms but thats not relevant :P)

You've set the "clearing" flag for both ObstacleLayer sources. In other words, I think you've asked the lidar source to remove depth data, and you've asked the depth source to remove lidar data.
Try using a separate ObstacleLayer for each source.

I added a separate layer for each source but it does not solve the issue as the PointCloud is still not reflected in the costmap
global_costmap:   plugins:     - {name: obstacle_layer1,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}     - {name: obstacle_layer2,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}   obstacle_layer1:     observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor      obstacle_layer2:     observation_sources: camera_sensor
For good measure I also tried to remove the laser_sensor and use only the camera as observation source but it was unsuccessful

You need to debug why depth camera is not giving you obstacle data. It's common to get the frame transform wrong for an optical frame where z-axis does not point upward.
